# Keyclock is not returning the refresh_token

Tags: token, keycloak, refresh, refresh-token

How do i get the refresh token ? I only get this response:

```
{
  "state": "XXX",
  "session_state": "XXX",
  "id_token": "XXX",
  "access_token": "XXX",
  "token_type": "Bearer",
  "expires_in": "86400"
}
```

https://URL/auth/realms/XXX/protocol/openid-connect/auth?client_id=XXX&redirect_uri=XXX&nonce=fe6c4327-ad30-4fd0-bd50-2e42d1537cd3&state=fe6c4327-ad30-4fd0-bd50-2e42d1537cd3&response_type=id_token+token&response_mode=fragment&scope=openid&login_hint=XXX

Does someone know what we have to do ? I am getting the URL from the backend. How do i get the refresh token out of it? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

you are only asking for the openid scope, you need to also ask for the offline_access scope, to get the refresh token.